# c# - changing the appearance of my windows form

Tags: c#, skin

I am developing a windows form. I want to change the physical appearance of the form and its controls. I was able to use the Skincrafter demo, however this is making the application substantially heavier. I am not satisfied with how "heavy" it feels when navigating through tabs, moving the window, etc. It's fairly simple program and I do not have this issue when not using skincrafter. When not using it, the GUI is very responsive and I want to keep it that way.

I've tried many different skins and the results are very similar in every case.

So I will not be using skincrafter unless someone points me out to possible reasons for this slower GUI. I followed their tutorial and didn't do anything else. Simple process. Before: fast GUI - after: slow GUI.

Can anyone recommend me another way to change the appearance of my controls/form? Is there way to programatically change the appearance of controls and form, without relying on a third party skinning software?

Note that I do not want my users to change skins. I want to apply one and that's it.

thank you
Steve

Edit: 
The project is far from done so I am going to give WPF some real good thoughts so I don't end up doing this when I have a 4x times as large as it is right now.
I've already start converting and it shouldn't be much of problem. Found timer and serialport cannot be front from the toolbox and timer are replaced by dispatchtimer. No big deal so far.
One another thing that makes me want to work with WPF is that I may have the need to make graphs (plotting) to show temperature over time. I use serialport to communicate with an external USB controller (virtual COM port) that reads a bunch of temperature sensors and fan speeds. I suspect graphing to be better with WPF.
One last thing: it's just about colors/fonts but more about looks of the buttons, looks of the actual window (border shapes). What I wanted to do was something similar that is done with html and css. I do want to have custom labels to give them the look of a "digital display" for real time temperatures and fan speed measurements.

again thanks all for the help provided!

Comment: You can take a look at suites of commercial controls, such as Telerik and DevExpress. But if you are really concerned about the UI I've heard that is better to move to WPF. It's not impossible in windows forms but certainly more difficult.

Comment: I would also suggest that you look into third parties for this. It's highly unlikely that you'll come up with something better in a reasonable delay. Either that or drop the skinning idea altogether.

Comment: `Can anyone recommend me another way to change the appearance of my controls/form?` - You're looking for [WPF](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/). It is the preferred UI framework when creating .Net based Windows Desktop applications. winforms is a really old technology that does not support any level of Richness or customization.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As with many smaller companies we do not have an in house programmer neither do we have the budget for subcontracting this. I have done some winform work before, this one is slightly more important as it will be used by end users as opposed to the ones I made before where I was the only user (lab application). I am wondering how difficult it will be to move the entire project to WPF but I will look into it. thanks

Comment: That almost entirely depends on how well you designed the project. If you follow some good practices and separated your logic from the UI, it should be fairly simple, since you can reuse the other layers.

Comment: @user3617652 moving the entire project to WPF will surely be less problematic that the endless hell of torture and pain involved in customizing winforms look and feel. If you really *need* to customize, your option is WPF. Otherwise you can just keep things as they are. If you need to customize *specific*, visually isolated parts of your UI (such as a specific widget or control), you can also use an `ElementHost` and integrate WPF content into winforms.

Comment: I just edited my question. I'll give WPF a fair go and see where that brings me. If I can implement graphing more easily than with winforms (I did before using an external dll - which was fine for personal use but for distribution that may not be possible) then WPF will definitely be the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

In the distant past, I added lightweight skinning to WinForms projects by subclassing the out-of-the-box controls (Label, TextBox, etc), and having that subclass read in appearance configuration (e.g. color, font) from an XML file (one could also use app.config).

That approach was easy to implement, and I saw no visible performance degradation.

If you just want a consistent, new look and don't need to enable the end user to pick from a variety of skins, the subclassing approach is very straightforward.  For example, to modify the look of a `Label`:

```
public MyLabel : Label
{
    MyLabel()
    {
        this.ForeColor = Colors.Blue;
    }
}
```

Then, everywhere you currently have a Label in your code, use a MyLabel instead.

If you are starting a new project, I would highly recommend using WPF instead.  It provides a much more flexible UI framework. One key feature is that it separates the look from the UI implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As with many smaller companies we do not have an in house programmer neither do we have the budget for subcontracting this. I have done some winform work before, this one is slightly more important as it will be used by end users as opposed to the ones I made before where I was the only user (lab application). I am wondering how difficult it will be to move the entire project to WPF but I will look into it. thanks

Comment: If it is an existing project and you don't have an in house programmer, evolving WinForms is probably a better solution.  I'll add a little more detail about how to subclass.  If you only need to improve the look and not make it a flexible skin (as in the user can pick which skin), the subclass strategy is really easy.

Comment: It's important to mention that the idea of *"customization"* is not just changing colors or UI elements' properties, and that real customization in winforms requires a technique called "owner draw", which is really cumbersome and tedious.

Comment: @HighCore: Sure, but the basic black-on-gray look can be significantly improved with the available properties.  The OP's objective is to make this app a bit nicer than the in-house ones since end clients will see it, within the constraints of limited money and programming expertise.

Comment: I edited my question. Seems like WPF may be a better way to go since my possible needs for graphing and window's border shapes needs. If I can't move my project to WPF I'll probably end up doing this though! thank you